# Split line into multiple lines of 42 Unix after last given char

Tags: unix, text, sed, fold

I have a text file in unix formed from multiple long lines

```
ALTER Tit como(titel('42423432;434235111;757567562;2354679;5543534;6547673;32322332;54545453'))
ALTER Mit como(Alt('432322;434434211;754324237562;2354679;5543534;6547673;32322332;54545453'))
```

I need to split each line in multiple lines of no longer than 42 characters.
The split should be done at the end of last ";", and 
so my ideal output file will be :

```
ALTER Tit como(titel('42423432;434235111; -

757567562;2354679;5543534;6547673; -

32322332;54545453'))

ALTER Mit como(Alt('432322;434434211; -

754324237562;2354679;5543534;6547673; -

32322332;54545453'))
```

I used fold -w 42 givenfile.txt | sed 's/ $/ -/g'

it splits the line but doesnt add the "-" at the end of the line and doesnt split after the ";".
any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F';' '
w{
    print""
}

{
    w=length($1)
    printf "%s",$1
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){
        if ((w+length($i)+1)<42){
            w+=length($i)+1
            printf";%s",$i
        } else {
            w=length($i)
            printf"; -\n%s",$i
        }
    }
}

END{
    print""
}
' file
```

This produces the output:

```
ALTER Tit como(titel('42423432;434235111; -
757567562;2354679;5543534;6547673; -
32322332;54545453'))
ALTER Mit como(Alt('432322;434434211; -
754324237562;2354679;5543534;6547673; -
32322332;54545453'))
```

#### How it works

Awk implicitly loops through each line of its input and each line is divided into fields.  This code uses a single variable `w` to keep track of the current width of the output line.

- `-F';'`

  Tell awk to break fields on semicolons.
- `w{print""}

  If the last line was not completed, `w>0`, then print a newline to terminate it before we start with a new line.
- `w=length($1); printf "%s",$1`

  Print the first field of the new line and set `w` according to its length.
- Loop over the remaining fields:

  ```
  for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){
      if ((w+length($i)+1)<42){
          w+=length($i)+1
          printf";%s",$i
      } else {
          w=length($i)
          printf"; -\n%s",$i
      }
  }
  ```

  This loops over the second to final fields of this line.  Whenever we reach the point where we can't print another field without exceeding the 42 character limit, we print `; -\n`.
- `END{print""}`

  Print a newline at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/.{1,42}$|.{1,41};/& -\n/g;s/...$//' file
```

This globally replaces 1 to 41 characters followed by a `;` or 1 to 42 characters followed by end of line with  `-\n`. The last string will have three characters too many and so they are deleted.